# How to edit inputs in an SQL cli after pressing enter?

Tags: postgresql, psql

This is what I currently have in my PostgreSQL cli

```
mydatabase=# CREATE TABLE person(
mydatabase(#    ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
mydatabase(#    NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
mydatabase(#    AGEE            INT     NOT NULL,
mydatabase(#    ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
mydatabase(#
```

Is it possible to edit data I have inputed and then pressed enter or should I just start again?

For example can I edit the third column name from `AGEE` to `AGE`?

Also how do I exit this "input mode" without exiting my database connection. I am currently using `crtl + c` or `\q` which also exits the database connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply enter `\edit` and the current buffer will be opened in an external editor. Once you save the buffer and close the editor the statement will be executed.

For more details on the `\edit` command and how to configure which editor to use, please [see the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#PSQL_EDITOR)